# Make a subquery to retrieve the answer of an attribute with Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I've 2 tables.

*attributes*
id, team_id, type_id, name, group

*answers_attributes*
id, name, person_id, attribute_id

I cannot modify the structure of my database. 
I would like to retrieve the attribute list of the current team with its answer.

For that, I'm looking for a way to combine two queries.

I’d like to get the list of attributes first. Then, using the ID of each attribute, retrieve its corresponding answer.

I tried to do this in one SQL request, but impossible.

```
$data = Attribute::where([
            ['type_id', $type_id],
            ['group', $group],
            ['team_id', Auth::user()->currentTeam->id]
        ])->addSelect(['answer' => function($query) {
            $query->select('name')
                ->from('answers_attributes')
                ->whereColumn('attribute_id', 'attributes.id')
                ->first();
        }])->orderBy('name', 'ASC')->get();
```

Do you have an idea?

Thank you

Comment: avoid using statements like Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use   [Subquery Selects](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#advanced-subqueries)

```
$data = Attribute::where([
            ['type_id', $type_id],
            ['group', $group],
            ['team_id', Auth::user()->currentTeam->id]
        ])->addSelect(['answer' => AnswerModel::select('name')
                ->whereColumn('attribute_id', 'attributes.id')
                ->limit(1)])->orderBy('attributes.name','ASC')->get();
```

here i have tow notes:

1- replace 'AnswerModel' with the Answer model you got.

2- in order by clause, make sure you write table name before column name 'name' because you have tow columns with name 'name' (in attributes and answers_attributes tables)